# Creating a different count for each 10 items in the list used for Dart Flutter carouselSlider

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an application like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The purpose of the application is to show the spelling of the numbers in the list.
Numbers and their spelling are in a list. List:

```
  List<wordAndMeaning> wordsList = [
    wordAndMeaning("1", "One", false),
    wordAndMeaning("2", "Two", false),
    wordAndMeaning("3", "Three", false),
    wordAndMeaning("4", "Four", false),
    wordAndMeaning("5", "Five", false),
    wordAndMeaning("6", "Six", false),
    wordAndMeaning("7", "Seven", false),
    wordAndMeaning("8", "Eight", false),
    wordAndMeaning("9", "Nine", false),
    wordAndMeaning("10", "Ten", false),
    wordAndMeaning("11", "Eleven", false),
    wordAndMeaning("12", "Twelve", false),
    wordAndMeaning("13", "Thirteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("14", "Fourteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("15", "Fifteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("16", "Sixteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("17", "Seventeen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("18", "Eighteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("19", "Nineteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("20", "Twenty", false),
```

For each list item, that is, for each number, there is 1 scrolling screen.
The number 1 on the first screen, the number 2 on the second screen, the number 3 on the third screen, and so on, up to 20. I took the screen of the first 3 numbers as a photo.

[image]

---

Let's get to the real problem. I want to make the system of showing the spelling of this number from 1 to 20. As such, there will be 30 scrolling screens. This will be very inefficient and there will be too many scrolling screens.

As a solution to this problem, I thought of showing 5 numbers on each page. In other words, there will be a total of 4 scrolling screens and it will show the writing of 5 numbers on each page. For example, the first screen will look like this:

1: One

2: Two

3: Three

4: Four

5: Five

Of course, these numbers will appear as a list and each number will have an eye icon. I want the list to show the spelling of the 3rd number when I press the eye icon of the 3rd number.

---

How can I do this system I described?

---

**Here is my code that creates a custom scrolling screen for each number:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:getwidget/getwidget.dart';

class sayilarLearn_1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<sayilarLearn_1> createState() => _sayilarLearn_1State();
}

class _sayilarLearn_1State extends State<sayilarLearn_1> {
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();
  List<wordAndMeaning> wordsList = [
    wordAndMeaning("1", "One", false),
    wordAndMeaning("2", "Two", false),
    wordAndMeaning("3", "Three", false),
    wordAndMeaning("4", "Four", false),
    wordAndMeaning("5", "Five", false),
    wordAndMeaning("6", "Six", false),
    wordAndMeaning("7", "Seven", false),
    wordAndMeaning("8", "Eight", false),
    wordAndMeaning("9", "Nine", false),
    wordAndMeaning("10", "Ten", false),
    wordAndMeaning("11", "Eleven", false),
    wordAndMeaning("12", "Twelve", false),
    wordAndMeaning("13", "Thirteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("14", "Fourteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("15", "Fifteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("16", "Sixteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("17", "Seventeen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("18", "Eighteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("19", "Nineteen", false),
    wordAndMeaning("20", "Twenty", false),

  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber[500],
        bottomOpacity: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Text("Numbers", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: Builder(builder: (context) {
        final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 160;
        return Column(
          children: [
            CarouselSlider(
              carouselController: _controller,
              options: CarouselOptions(
                height: height,
                viewportFraction: 1.0,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
              ),
              items: wordsList.map((wordAndMeaning word) { // <<<<<<<<<!!!!!
                return Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                
                                if (word.showMeaning) ...[
                                  Text(word.meaning,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 35, color: Colors.white)),
                                
                                Text(word.word,
                                    style:
                                        TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                                ],                          
                                if (!word.showMeaning) ...[
                                  Text(word.word,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 35, color: Colors.white)),
                                ],
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye_sharp),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            iconSize: 25,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                word.showMeaning = !word.showMeaning;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                  
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          
                        ),
                        width: 55,
                        height: 55,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, size: 30, color: Colors.white,),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _controller.previousPage(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
                            );
                          },
                          // köşeyi yuvarlaştırma:
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          ),
                          
                        )
                        
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        width: 55,
                        height: 55,
                        child: Container(
                          child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 30, color: Colors.white,),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _controller.nextPage(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
                            );
                          },
                          // köşeyi yuvarlaştırma:
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          ),
                          
                        )
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
        
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is by creating a new widget that can act as a list.

For example:

```
class WordAndMeaningColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  const WordAndMeaningColumn({
    Key? key,
    required this.wordAndMeanings,
  }): super(key: key);

  final List<WordAndMeaning> wordAndMeanings;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: wordAndMeanings.map((data) {
        return Expanded(
          child: WordAndMeaning(
            word: data.word,
            meaning: data.meaning,
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class WordAndMeaning extends StatefulWidget {
  const WordAndMeaning({
    Key? key,
    required this.word,
    required this.meaning,
  }): super(key: key);

  final String word;
  final String meaning;
   
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _WordAndMeaningState();
}

class _WordAndMeaningState extends State<WordAndMeaning> {

  bool showMeaning = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(widget.word),
      subtitle: Visibility(
        visible: showMeaning,
        child: Text(widget.meaning),
      ),
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye_sharp),
        color: Colors.white,
        iconSize: 25,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            showMeaning = !showMeaning;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}


class SayilarLearn1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const SayilarLearn1({Key? key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SayilarLearn1State();
}

class _SayilarLearn1State extends State<SayilarLearn1> {
  
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();

  final List<WordAndMeaningColumn> wordsList = const [
    WordAndMeaningColumn(
      wordAndMeanings: [
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'One', meaning: '1'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Two', meaning: '2'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Three', meaning: '3'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Four', meaning: '4'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Five', meaning: '5'),
      ],
    ),
    WordAndMeaningColumn(
      wordAndMeanings: [
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Six', meaning: '6'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Seven', meaning: '7'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Eight', meaning: '8'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Nine', meaning: '9'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Ten', meaning: '10'),
      ],
    ),
    WordAndMeaningColumn(
      wordAndMeanings: [
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Eleven', meaning: '11'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Twelve', meaning: '12'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Thirteen', meaning: '13'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Fourteen', meaning: '14'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Fifteen', meaning: '15'),
      ],
    ),
    WordAndMeaningColumn(
      wordAndMeanings: [
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Sixteen', meaning: '16'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Seventeen', meaning: '17'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Eighteen', meaning: '18'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Nineteen', meaning: '19'),
        WordAndMeaning(word: 'Twenty', meaning: '20'),
      ],
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber[500],
        bottomOpacity: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: const Text('Numbers', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: CarouselSlider.builder(
              carouselController: _controller,
              itemCount: wordsList.length,
              options: CarouselOptions(
                viewportFraction: 1,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, itemIndex, pageViewIndex) {
                return wordsList[itemIndex];
              },
            ),
          ),

          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      width: 55,
                      height: 55,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _controller.previousPage(
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                            curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
                          );
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.blue,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10,),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      width: 55,
                      height: 55,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _controller.nextPage(
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                            curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
                          );
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.blue,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I refactored some of your code to simplify some things. Hopefully this will point you in the right direction!